# assigning a window to another window in ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

Whenever I do this and print the window, the upper left corner is open.

```
WINDOW* win1 = newwin(10, 10, 10, 10);
WINDOW* win2 = newwin(10, 10, 10, 10);
win1 = win2;

box(win1, 0, 0);
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: The example isn't a complete program; no one can guess what the missing parts are.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].